# Swift syntax 'case let' in for loop is confusing

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

If the goal is to have 'result' represent an object in the 'results' array, why not drop `case let` in the following and just have 'for result in' instead ? I don't understand why `case let` is required here.

```
if let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
    for case let result in json["results"] {
        if let restaurant = Restaurant(json: result) {
            restaurants.append(restaurant)
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "query": "sandwich",
    "results_count": 12,
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Caffè Macs",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 37.330576,
                "lng": -122.029739
            },
            "meals": ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

REF: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case there is no need to use `case let` with for loop, because you want all objects of `results` response, If you want to understand how `case let` is use check this.

```
let albumDic = [
    ("Red", 2014),
    ("1989", 2014),
    ("Fearless", 2008),
    ("Speak Now", 2008)
]

for case let (album, 2014) in albumDic {
    print("Album \(album) was released in 2014")
}
```

**Output**

```
Album Red was released in 2014
Album 1989 was released in 2014
```

**Note:** You can directly use for in loop no need to use `case let` since you want all the objects, so you need to write like this.

```
if let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]]{
    for result in results {

    }
}
```

For more details you can check this [tutorial](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-for-in-filtering/) of for in.

Comment: Taylor *Swift*... I see what you did there